# Can't find default margin for body element in user-agent stylesheet

Tags: html, css

I wrote a simple `html`

```
<h1 class="one">Hello</h1>
```

When I check the margin for `body` element in Firefox (version 90.0.2 64 bit), I get `8px`. This comes from default style sheet for the browser. I wanted to check this default style sheet given at `resource://gre-resources/forms.css` in Firefox. But I could not find `margin: 8px` for the `body` element. Can anybody help me understand this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default style sheet for firefox is under `resource://gre-resources/html.css` and there you find:

```css
body {
  display: block;
  margin: 8px;
}
```

(in my case at line 122)

Answer (score 1):

I think you were looking for it in the wrong file, the margin for `body` comes from `resource://gre-resources/html.css` file.

```css
body {
  display: block;
  margin: 8px;
}
```

**check this image**

[image]